# Fill in blanks in excel with vba

Tags: vba, excel

Im working with a large dataset in excel whose boundaries may change with updates.
I need an automated method to fill in all blank cells with a place holder such as 'n/a'. 
Is there a quick way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop through cells in your range and wherever you encounter a blank, you'll need the following code

```
' e.g. you need to make cell A2 read #N/A, i.e. the error value
ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)
```

If you simply need to put **the string "N/A"** and not the equivalent of the **error function** `=NA()` do have a look at the code provided by Gary's Student.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub NoBlanka()
    For Each r In Selection
        If r.Text = "" Then
            r.Value = "n/a"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**Select** your group of cells and run the macro.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on requirements, but maybe give this a try. Should be entered into your worksheet code module, and the worksheet name where commented should be changed to whatever name you are using for your sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Static r As Range

    With Worksheets("mySheet")

        If .UsedRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        If r Is Nothing Then
            Set r = .UsedRange
            On Error Resume Next
            r.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Sub
        End If

        On Error GoTo ERREUR
        If r.Address <> .UsedRange.Address Then
            On Error goto 0
            Set r = .UsedRange
            On Error Resume Next
            r.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If

    End With

ERREUR:

Set r = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need. I used a Macro-recorder in Excel.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "na"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need vba to do this. You can use the special cells.

In the Home tab of the ribbon, click Find and Select (in the Editing section at the right of the ribbon) and choose Go To Special

Select Blank Cells. Then ok. This will select all your blank cells.

Now type = and your place holder. So for n/a you would simply type ='n/a